Late 90s / early 2000s YA - Sick child protaganist, some teleporting/time travelling stranger with an unusual device
One of those "Wow, what was that book I read again?" moments. Thought about this book on and off since I read it in high school (between 2000 and '06).
Not a lot of plot points to go on here, but I strongly remember that the protagonist was a child or young teen and they were sick and getting sicker quickly.
I really only remember one sequence from the book where they "party" up with an older teen. This teen seems to be from somewhere else, possibly not the planet, or even timeline. They carry with them a mysterious device that was described as looking like an asthma inhaler, but it allowed them to either time travel, or teleport, or perhaps move about without being seen. It's used to enter a department store to acquire a new outfit, although they accidentally leave the tags on, and this is possibly pointed out by the protagonist.
I also seem to remember that the kid was sick or dying because of the device though, perhaps whenever they used it?
Does this ring a bell for anyone? I have no idea if this was part of a series, or even when the book was released exactly.
